# DLCleanerlite.exe launches at Windows startup but is not in startup folder or in msconfig.exe startup tab

Tags: windows, registry, malware, virus

I don't know how i got DLCleanerLite.exe installed in my Windows 7 computer, but every time my Windows loads up, DLCleanerLite loads up.

I have checked

1. Add/Remove Program feature in the Window's Control Panel.
2. Startup Folder.
3. MSConfig.exe Startup Tab.
4. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

But I don't see anything related to DLCleanerLite.exe

DLCleanerLite.exe is at location
C:\Program Files (x86)\CBS Interactive\Download App\DLCleanerLite\DLCleanerLite.exe

Does anyone know how I can safely remove it? Can I just delete that exe file?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Many experts agree, if you don't use it you should remove it!](http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/DL-Cleaner-Lite-119222-program.aspx).

You can uninstall DL Cleaner Lite from your computer by using the Add/Remove Program feature in the Window's Control Panel.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I forgot to mention that the software is not listed in Add/Remove Program feature in the Window's Control Panel either.

Comment: You can use excellent [Autoruns for Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb963902) to show autstarts.